# Translate Tier Price and Group Price wording in Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, localisation, products-management, inline-translations

How can i translate Tier Price and Group Price wording in Admin Section -> New Product?

With inline translate it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: put more  details..........

Comment: Are you only using inline translations, or have you used a language pack?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Group price and tier price use special templates and display the **attribute label** without using the translation methods (this is why you don't see the red lines)

You can change the attribute label in "Catalog > Manage Attributes", but you will always see the value that you enter as "Admin value" there, regardless of the choosen language. So this is only a solution if all your admins use the same language.

Answer (score -1):

I found that those only two labels have not been translated in the magento admin interface. It's because in the template files group and tier, the echo label doesn't use the translation function.

In app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml and tier.phtml about line 40, you need to edit the echo of the td class="label".

```
echo $this->getElement()->getLabel()
```

become

```
echo __($this->getElement()->getLabel())
```

After this edit, you can add or edit your translation csv to admin :
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv for french

Hope this answer will help someone